# How to render Mandelbulb-style 3D fractals

Tags: 3d, rendering, fractals

I'm interested in experimenting with equations for 3D fractals (a la Mandelbulb).  Does anyone know of a framework that will allow me to supply a 3-coordinate, Mandelbrot-style function, identifying a point as being contained or not contained within a set, and render the surface form of the resulting set in 3D?

Obviously, a solution that can use the GPU to do the processing would be better.

Comment: Mandelbulb in 1k of JavaScript. http://jsbin.com/avukop/1

Answer (score 1):

The [3D Mandelbulb Ray Tracer](http://www.subblue.com/projects/mandelbulb) by [subblue](http://www.subblue.com/) has been getting impressive results.  It uses the GPU.  It was used to produce this [fly through](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bO9ugnn8DbE).  Maybe not as programmable as you'd like.

According to documentation, this project on Github may fit the bill: http://github.com/vain/GPUTracer.  You can find more by Googling "mandelbulb raytracer github"

Comment: But is it programatically invokable?